# Converting 24V AC into 230V AC

Tags: voltage, current, ac, transformer

In my basement I have 24V AC power outlet. I need it to be 230V.

I found some fairly big, old transformer core, on the one side of it I winded 3 turns of standard power cable, on the other side I winded 30 turns. When I connect either of those sides to power outlet (while the other coil remains unconnected), the light in the whole basement goes down (it doesn't break, it starts to glow really low). As I said, It doesn't matter which coil I plug in, the result is the same. Also, when I connect the 3-turns coil into my outlet, the transformer is making quiet buzzing, while, when I connect the 30-turns coil, it starts buzzing kinda loud.

Why does the light in the basement go down? Why is the transformer buzzing? How do I convert this 24V into 230V? I only have this big transformer core, some standard home power cables (the ones that you are using to power your pc, tv, etc.), and some unisolated wires (those were in the transformer previously, but now I think they are useless, since they got no insulation on them).

Answer (score 3):

The lights are dimming because the transformer is drawing so much power that the 24 V is getting dragged down.

Overall your strategy doesn't sound good.  Even with the right transformer, you don't get more power in that out.  What current is the 24 V limited to?  Let's say 2 A as example.  That means you can draw 48 W maximum.  At 230 V that would be 210 mA, and that is without any of the inevitable losses in a transformer trying to step up 24 V to 230 V.  A hand wound transformer without careful design probably won't even get to 50% efficiency in this case, and even that is a stretch.  That would leave at most 24 W of power at 230 V in this example.  What are you going to run off of that?

You say this "basement" only has 24 V power.  That is hard to believe, but apparently somewhere there is 230 V power in this house.  It would be better to use that directly, which is probably where the 24 V is coming from.

Then there is the issue of someone with your apparent knowledge messing with 230 V.  It only takes a few mA to kill you or do serious harm, the inefficiency of a transformer won't protect you.

Given all the above, the basic answer is this is not a project you should be persuing.

Comment: About two years ago there was 230V in the basement. And then administration of the building changed it to 24V. I assume they put a step-down transformer somewhere. Also all you are telling me, is that this is physically impossible? I was looking at e-bay to buy some 24V-230V transformers, you are telling me that they would not work either?

Comment: No one has said this is impossible.. Please re-read all the comments

Answer (score 1):

You have the turns ratio correct (1:10) to step up the voltage. However, the primary side impedance with just 3  turns is just far too low resulting in excessive current being drawn. 
You are probably saturating the core as well compounding the situation.

The lights dim due to the current level. Why do you have a 24v ac feed, what is generating that

Please, please rewind the xfmr with a lot more turns.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Does the insulation on the wire matter? If I used unisolated wire and put insulation only between coils, would that work? 2. If I had, lets say 1000 short wires, and I would wind them together around the core one time (1 turn). Would that count as 1000 turns on the core?